# Resetting a form

Tags: angular, angular-template-form

In AngularJs I used to use the ng-submitted class for my form validation but it does not appear in Angular when you submit a form. I have written a directive that adds a class submitted to a form and removes it on reset

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appForm]'
})
export class FormDirective implements OnDestroy {
  private subscription: Subscription;

  constructor(el: ElementRef, form: NgForm) {
    this.subscription = form.ngSubmit.subscribe(() => {
      el.nativeElement.classList.add('submitted');
    });
    form.onReset = () => {
      el.nativeElement.classList.remove('submitted');
    };
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.subscription) {
      this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
  }
}
```

This works great when you reset the form with a reset button. The problem I am having is when I need to reset with values other than setting all the bindings to null I need to reset the form with the ngForm resetForm method but this does not trigger the onReset method and I can't find a way to tap into the form being reset this way.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u2rlx9

Answer (score 0):

`NgForm` directive has a [`submitted`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/8.2.8/packages/forms/src/directives/ng_form.ts#L109) property that you can use. I don't see no need to use a directive in this case.

Instead you can use that boolean property for your needs, for whatever needs. If you want to set some class (like) in your stackblitz sample, you can use [`ngClass`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass) for that, that is the "angular way". You shouldn't manipulate the DOM unless **really** needed, and in this case it's definitely not needed as we can use angular bindings, which is recommended.

Here we can also use `*ngIf`:

```html
<form #form="ngForm">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  <button type="reset">Reset</button>
  <button type="button" (click)="form.resetForm()">Angular reset</button>
  <div *ngIf="form.submitted">Submitted</div>
  <div *ngIf="!form.submitted">Not submitted</div>
</form>
```

**[Your forked STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qbaqhc?file=src/app/app.component.html)**

Comment: I want to add one css rule that hides all the validation messages if the form is not submitted, I don't want to have to add *ngIf="form.submitted" to every validation message.

Comment: My requirements are a lot more involved that the simplified question. I am building a forms library that hides validation from the user https://github.com/adriandavidbrand/ngx-ez and a StackBlitz of a form https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8brst8

Comment: You can see that none of the validation messages are in the template, it is all hidden from the monkeys and controlled by css, having the submitted class on the form allows a large amount of the work to be done purely with css

Comment: @AdrianBrand - You shouldn't be keeping things you don't need in the DOM. css will just hide the element. It would be better if you used `ngIf` so it gets removed when from the DOM when it's not needed.+36

Answer (score -1):

You just need to call this to reset the form

```
resetForm() {
   this.form.reset();
}
```